# What is the Simplest software solution for format shifting DVD library to use in a media station?

Tags: dvd, media-player

I noticed that format shifting is soon to become legal in the UK and was wondering if there was a simple solution to ripping a large number of DVDs to a computer with a nice TV friendly UI.

Ideally I'd like something that let me insert a DVD rip it spit it out and repeat.

I'd like a UI that splits my DVD's out by genre and by name, and groups TV series together by season and by show. I don't mind entering the metadata manually, but would prefer if it consulted an online database and just figured it out like my CD ripping tool does.

Am I living in a dream world or does such a tool exist?

If there isn't a single tool what tools can i cobble together to have similar functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handbrake is probably the most capable transcoder/format shifter. It's also free.

However, because most DVDs have various forms of copy protection, even with format shifting becoming legal, this will not automatically make all your DVDs readable by ripping software.

You can either purchase an encryption defeating tool (Slysoft has some good ones), or wait for the inevitable hacks that will make this easy and free.